# TYPO3 system extension seo not working as expected

Tags: typo3, seo, typo3-10.x

TYPO3 10.4.16

I'm trying to use the new feature of seo, to set the `xslFile` .

```
plugin.tx_seo {
  config {
    xmlSitemap {
      sitemaps {
        pages {
          config {
            xslFile = EXT:mairlist/Resources/Public/CSS/sitemap.xsl
            excludedDoktypes = 137, 138
            additionalWhere = AND (no_index = 0 OR no_follow = 0)
            #rootPage = <optionally specify a different root page. (default: rootPageId from site configuration)>
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I tried it also with `Sitemap.xsl` and `/Sitemap.xsl` but in neither cases I could find any file on this locations. The default location should be `EXT:seo/Resources/Public/CSS/mySite.xsl` . On this location I could find a file, but it is 1 month old.
Where does seo store the file?

It it possible, that seo saves directly the Sitemap file in the root directory?

This would allow me to use a redirect for the root page again, to the startpage.

**Edit:**

The xslfile specifies an input file and not an output file. It seems to be used for changing the format of the sitemap xml file and not the location.
So currently there is no way to tell seo to create a physical sitemap.xml file on a specific location.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are subject to a misunderstanding.
The XSL-file is not generated by the seo extension, but used for a layout of the sitemap.

You can provide an existing XSL-File which is used for generating the sitemap.
The sitemap is accessed by default with https://yourdomain.com/?type=1533906435

See the [manual](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/ApiOverview/XmlSitemap/Index.html#how-to-access-your-xml-sitemap) for information about accessing the sitemap and at the [end of that page](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/ApiOverview/XmlSitemap/Index.html#path-to-sitemap-xslfile) about the usage of XSL-files.

Comment: The xsl file is is like a template file for the sitemap output. Output as there is no file generated. Like any page in TYPO3 also the sitemap is generated on the fly (except short caching). As you have a special pagetype (in general) no page Id is necessary. You should have a rewrite from sitemap.xml to index.php?type=1234567 (see manual)